# Destroy JMS Message Listener

Tags: jms, message, listener

How to destroy my JMS Message listener ?

I tried writing a code to set it to null, but that does not help

Comment: I dont have an answer but just because you dont have a reference to the listener doesnt mean everyone lost their copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the close() on the consumer that have the message listener set.

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination, selector);
consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
...
/* Listening is working */
...
consumer.close();
/* Listening is NOT working anymore */
```